# problems in ics updated devices

Tags: android

Recently I started receive emails form my users, that they phones updated to ics, and now images that they save with my application not showing in android's gallery application after that. They say that with file explorer they can see files, but not with gallery app and that they didn't experienced any this kind of problems before ics update.

I'm certainly calling  scanFile with MediaScannerConnection after onMediaScannerConnected event.

**Update**:
I forgot mention that image mime type was set to "image/*" not to "image/jpeg" or "image/png".

Comment: Have you tried your application in the ICS emulator?

Comment: I tried it no real ICS device, on Galaxy nexus, and it works fine. I think that problem may be with updated devices, that updated from Gingerbread.

Comment: this happens on Droidrazr that is updated to ics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
It's because of setting "image/*" mime type. In ICS it's does not recognized and in some devices Gallery application can't recognize this mime type, setting mime type to null resolves the issue.